# Updating a list of something w/ RxSwift in a ViewModel

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I have a VM that renders a list of "nodes". Each node has an `isCompleted` and `isRead` property.  They are rendered in a tableview and each cell has buttons to toggle those properties.

On page load, I fetch the list from the server.  Now, I simply want to update those nodes.  In my VM, I have attempted over 20 approaches with various operators, strategies, approaches, etc.. But with each attempt there's always the same issue.

I'm aware that this is literally just updating something, or View -> ViewModel communication.  Nonetheless, I've spent an embarrassing amount of hours racking my brain trying to model this.  So I must be missing some very fundamental aspect of RxSwift, MVVM and how to model mutations.

Here is my latest attempt.

```
  let updates = Observable<(NodeIdentifier, AttribUpdate)?>.merge([
        toggleMarkReadSubject.map { ($0, AttribUpdate.isRead) },
        toggleFavoriteSubject.map { ($0, AttribUpdate.isFavorited) }
        ]).startWith(nil)

    nodes = Observable.combineLatest(dataFromService, updates, resultSelector: { (nodes, update) in
        guard let update = update else { return nodes }

        switch update.1 {
        case .isFavorited:
            return nodes.withFavoritedToggled(atId: update.0)
        case .isRead:
            return nodes.withMarkReadToggled(atId: update.0)
        }
    }).debug("new nodes", trimOutput: false)
```

I have some Subjects that map the toggle events to a tuple with the nodeIdentifier and the update operation (using an enum with cases for each update type)

`nodes` is my main output that drives the tableview.  I `combineLatest`'d the `nodesFromService` (the original nodes from the service/api).

Now, I get events of `[Node]` where the toggled property looks like the following: `[false, true, true, true, true]`.  So it always goes from `false -> true` because `combineLatest` always takes the initial node array from `nodesFromService`.

Here's what is driving me insane..  No matter which way I slice it, this is a cyclical dependency.  What I really need is for the `updates` (the toggle events) to be combined with the `"final nodes"` stream (the stream that actually remembers the updates).  But, if I were even able to do that, I'd run into a recursive situation.  Because the `updates` are what produces that `"final nodes"` stream in the first place! I feel totally lost.  I greatly appreciate help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find two options here.

---

Because you are not storing nowhere current state of nodes, you may add a subject to your ViewModel. In such case you can save previous state of the nodes.

```
let nodesSubject = BehaviorSubject(value: [Node]())

...

updateSubject.map { updates in
    guard let nodes = try? nodesSubject.value() else { return [] }

    // Filter

}.subscribe(nodesSubject) // Save updated nodes back to subject

// update nodes subject on on next (you can do this as side effect instead with do(onNext:))
dataFromService.subscribe(nodesSubject)
```

In this case you'll end up having a subscription in ViewModel, which may not be the perfect solution.

---

Second approach is by using [scan](http://rxmarbles.com/#scan) operator.

```
let nodesStream = Observable.combineLatest(dataFromService, updates).scan(nil) { (previousValues, updates) -> [String] in
    var nodes = previousValues ?? updates.0

    // Filter

    return nodes
}
```

This approach may be a bit more hard to follow.

Comment: thanks.  i really want to avoid the first approach.  it seems to lead a very imperative and not reactive approach with lots of state and subscriptions in the VM. I wrote a version using `scan` and it appears to be working.  The second parameter of the `scan` closure is `(NodeIdentifier, [Node])` and it seems that the second tuple element there isn't even required.  Its a bit ugly but I'm sure I can refactor it to look nice.  What do you think? - https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/5c2b878ec62263592a8f31b7ffa83450

Comment: It seems to solve the problem, but it's quite hard to understand if you're not aware what you are trying to do there.

Comment: i'm not aware of what i'm trying to do?  i'm fetching a list of objects and displaying them in a tableview.  each cell has a two buttons some bool's in each object.  so i'm not sure what you mean?  but as I said (and checked again), using `scan` does accomplish what I want.

Comment: Sorry for my confusing comment. I was saying that anyone who is going to join the project and try to understand what's going on there will have a bit of a hard time. Just saying that such stream operations are hard to follow.

Comment: sure.  but i'd prefer to do it the best way, not the easy way.  its mainly a couple other devs and most know Rx fairly well.